# jQuery ajax returning entire aspx content

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to make an ajax call using jQuery to C# method.

```
$(".imgDbAttachment").on("click", function (e) {
            debugger;
            var fileName = $(this).attr('data-attchment-id');
            fileExt = $(this).attr('data-attchment-type');
            loadAjaxImage(fileName, fileExt);
        });

 function loadAjaxImage(id,type) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../CommonDesign/Test.aspx/GetImage",
                data:{
                    'attachmentId': id,
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (console && console.log) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }


public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var str = this.Request.Url;
    }


   [WebMethod]
    public string GetImage(string attachmentId)
    {

             return "hello";
    }
```

But when I am making ajax call,the control is hitting the PageLoad() & not the GetImage() & this in turn returning entire aspx page content

check these links,

1. [$.ajax Returning HTML of the page instead of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156529/ajax-returning-html-of-the-page-instead-of-results)
2. some other as well

But still the same issue.

Any suggestion/highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make `GetImage()` **static**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetImage(string attachmentId)
{
   return "hello";
}
```

More reading **[here](http://Why%20WebMethod%20declared%20as%20Static?)**

Comment: Checked,but this is throwing 500 internal server error

Comment: on removing the contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", it runs but still the same full page contenet

Comment: you can leave the `contenType` in and do `console.log(data.d);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a Post as well when you click the button. It is best to add a

```
return false;
```

to the last line of your function

```
$(".imgDbAttachment").on("click", function (e) {
            debugger;
            var fileName = $(this).attr('data-attchment-id');
            fileExt = $(this).attr('data-attchment-type');
            loadAjaxImage(fileName, fileExt);
return false;
        });
```